# Design for Authentication schema for A WebService called by Mobile Client

Tags: iphone, web-services, authentication, jakarta-ee, oauth

I've a (Json) WebService that have multiple methods.

I need to call these methods in a Mobile App. And need to add authentication schema to this Service.

Note, there's a Login screen in the Mobile app.

**What is the best way to accomplish that?**

*One suggest (but I don't desire) is:*

Have the All WebService methods to have two extra Parameters (UserName and Password), thus send the authentication with each request.

*Other Suggestion might be:*

What If I used `OAuth` authentication schema; which as I could understand is to send Username&password once, and then have the server send the client some token and then the client uses it in subsequent calls.

Please suggest me!

Answer (score 2):

Sending username/email+password with every request requires you to persist both within the application which is bad.

`OAuth` is the perfect way to implement authentication for mobile devices. Following standards is good.

The bottom line is that it doesn't make sense to make any short-term expiring token for the app (unless it's a banking app or an app accessing CIA/FBI/UNB facilities).

Comment: Can you point me to a place where can I start reading about OAuth and Mobile auth?

Comment: You can get the basic protocol overview on [OAuth official site](http://oauth.net), and on this [page](http://oauth.net/code) you can find the implementations both for consumer and server side.